# How to Extract hours portion from time

Tags: java, datetime, time

I have time "22:00:30" in String format I want to just extract the hour 22 from it. Can I get some help. I tried searching but everywhere DateTime has been used whereas in my case there is no date

Thank you all for the help...

Now I just wanted to know if the time is "22.00.30" how should I extract the hours from the time... above with colons work woth LocalTime but time with "dot" gives me exception. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it into a java.time.LocalTime object. Then use the getHour() method to extract hour value.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("22:00:30");
System.out.print(time.getHour()); //to get hour value
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.split(":")` will return a list of each of the substrings that were separated by the `:` character. Try this:

```
s = "22:00:30"
hour = s.split(":")[0]
```

Comment: While it works, IMHO we should clearly prefer using the specialized time library, in this case `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use *java.time* classes, specifically [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
int hour = LocalTime.parse( "22:00:30" ).getHour() ;
```